# Concurrency in Go on a single core machine

Tags: go, goroutine

will there be concurrency if a Go program containing atleast 2 goroutine calls runs on a single core machine?

Comment: Yes, there can be concurrency, because concurrency is not the same thing as parallelism.

Comment: depends on what exactly the goroutines are doing. maybe they are waiting the HTTP responses )

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes, there will be concurrency.

How effective it will be depends on the nature of the problem your program is solving. If your program is completely CPU bound (calculating some math equations, etc), then you're not going to gain performance from having 2 goroutines, but it will still work concurrently. If your program is I/O bound - such as a network server, concurrency will likely lead to better performance even in a single-CPU case.

Please watch the [Concurrency is not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/waza-talk) talk by Rob Pike.